# PineScript not yielding expected variable value

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

hopefully someone has a better understanding than I do.  I get how pinescript is executed, ie, all the code per tick/candle, but I'm not seeing what I expect to see given that.

Here's a snippet:

```
//@version=5
strategy("test", overlay=true)

ema = ta.ema(close, 200)

swingLow(candles) =>
    l = low
    for i=1 to candles
        l := low[i] < l ? low[i] : l
    l


var float prevSwingLow = 0.0

if ta.crossover(close, ema)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    prevSwingLow := swingLow(3)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="Buy", stop=prevSwingLow, limit=close+(close*.01), comment=str.tostring(prevSwingLow))
```

What I'm seeing is that the prevSwingLow variable is being set to a value different (or zero in this case) than what it should be at the time of the entry being placed (ie, at the time of the `strategy.entry()` call.  I hope I'm making sense.  If I use `stop=swingLow(3)` for the `strategy.exit()` call then it uses a swing low value also not correct at the time of the original entry - it appears to be using a value at the time of the `strategy.exit()` call (in my other tests with a different entry criteria, but zero in this case).  I'm obviously missing something basic here with pinescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the variable `prevSwingLow` is updated every time the condition `ta.crossover(close, ema)` becomes `true`, which can happen during an already open long order, plot the condition and `prevSwingLow` to spot the changes:

```
bgcolor(ta.crossover(close, ema) ? color.red : na)
plot(prevSwingLow)
```

[image]

To avoid updating the `prevSwingLow` variable when there is no order executed, check the currently open order using the `strategy.position_size` built-in:

```
if ta.crossover(close, ema)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    if strategy.position_size == 0
        prevSwingLow := swingLow(3)
```

[image]